# How to get rid of defects in that ComplexPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, special-functions, complex

I mean the result of

```
ComplexPlot3D[Sin[z]/MittagLefflerE[10,z],{z,-1-I, 8 + I},Exclusions->None, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Its blow-up

```
ComplexPlot3D[Sin[z]/MittagLefflerE[10, z],{z,-1 - I, 4 + I},Exclusions -> None,PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

does not live up to expectations though takes a lot of time.  [The Mittag-Leffler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function) is an entire function without any singularities.

Comment: The result of `ComplexPlot[Sin[z]/MittagLefflerE[10, z], {z, -1 - I, 4 + I}, 
 Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 100]` is alright.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use arbitrary-precision rather than machine precision by specifying the [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html).

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)

ComplexPlot3D[Sin[z]/MittagLefflerE[10, z], {z, -1 - I, 8 + I}, 
 Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  `ComplexPlot3D[Sin[z]/MittagLefflerE[10, z], {z, -1 - I, 4 + I}, 
 Exclusions -> None, WorkingPrecision -> 15]`  produces a nice plot  on a fresh kernel on my comp during approximately 20 minutes. The resources of my comp are not exhausted.

Comment: On my laptop with a fresh kernel and using the code in your comment, the `AbsoluteTiming` was less than 4 minutes.